# Finding numbers that are multiples of and divisors of 2 user inputted numbers

Tags: python, loops, math, while-loop

I have an assignment for Python to take 2 user inputted numbers (making sure the 1st number is smaller than the second) and to find numbers that are multiples of the first, and divisors of the second.. I'm only allowed to use a while loop (new condition my teacher added today..) I've done it with a for loop:

```
N_small = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
N_big = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
numbers = ""


if N_small > N_big:
    print("The first number should be smaller. Their value will be swapped.")
    N_small, N_big = N_big, N_small
for x in range(N_small, N_big+1, N_small):
    if N_big % x == 0:
        numbers += str(x) + " " 

print("The numbers are: ", numbers)
```

I'm not asking for the answer to how to do this with a while loop - but I just need a hint or two to figure out how to start doing this... Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: Hints: First find the divisors of the second number. To find divisors, loop through all numbers from 2 through sqrt(n2) (why?) and keep the ones for which the remainder, when dividing n2 by the number in question, is zero (why?). Then loop through those numbers you kept so far, and keep the ones for which the remainder when dividing by n1, is zero.

Comment: @RobertDodier: I think he's asking how to replace his `for` loop with an equivalent `while` loop, not for a different algorithm (that would be naturally written with a `for` loop, just like his existing code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert *any* `for` loop into a `while` loop trivially. Here's what a `for` loop means:

```
for element in iterable:
    stuff(element)

iterator = iter(iterable)
while True:
    try:
        element = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    stuff(element)
```

Of course that's not what your teacher is asking for here, but think about how it works. It's iterating all of the values in `range(N_small, N_big+1, N_small)`. You need some way to get those values—ideally *without* iterating them, just with basic math.

So, what *are* those values? They're `N_small`, then `N_small+N_small`, then `N_small+N_small+N_small`, and so on, up until you reach or exceed `N_big+1`. So, how could you generate those numbers without an iterable?

Start with this:

```
element = N_small
while element ???: # until you reach or exceed N_big+1
    stuff(element)
    element ??? # how do you increase element each time?
```

Just fill in the `???` parts. Then look out for where you could have an off-by-one error that makes you do one loop too many, or one too few, and how you'd write tests for that. Then write those tests. And then, assuming you passed the tests (possibly after fixing a mistake), you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate over all the numbers, only the multiples...

```
small, big = 4, 400
times = 1
while times < big / small:
    num = times * small
    if big % num == 0: print(num)
    times += 1
```